# Why doesn't Heroku show the default Rails page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Following chapter (1) of the Ruby on Rails tutorial, I was able to successfuly push the application to "Heroku" using:

> git push heroku master
>   But, when I open the website, I get a page with the following:

App crashed
This application is temporarily offline.
If you're the administrator of this app, please check your heroku logs for the backtrace.

Why is that? And, why don't I see the default Rails page?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at your Heroku logs? type `heroku logs` into your console.

Comment: The log access is really limited. Install the free heroku add on hoptoad. Then you'll get error backtraces emailed to you and available online. Pretty much essential with heroku.

Comment: I saw my app crash on Heroku today a few times for no valid reason. Issued heroku restart and all was well....

Answer (score 2):

In any situation where heroku gives you an error message in production, type heroku logs into your terminal. This will usually point you in the right direction.

http://docs.heroku.com/logs-exceptions

Also check your localhost and make sure you have migrated the database if one exists.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I managed that by adding ":group => :development" to the gem 'sqlite3-ruby'.... line in Gemfile based on: http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

Are you able navigate to default local rails website at http://localhost:3000 and see the defaut site?

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I managed that by adding ":group => :development" to the gem 'sqlite3-ruby'.... line in Gemfile based on: http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book